# how to replace an instance created by Terraform

Tags: terraform

I created multiple nodes using terraform and then I deployed these nodes as a cluster using ansible.

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "cluster"
  count = 6
  machine_type = "e2.micro"
  ...
}
```

Now suppose one of the nodes has some issue such as hardware issue so I have to destroy it and launch another node and then deploy it using Ansible.

How can I destroy it and then launch a new one with that same Terraform code? Using the above Terraform I only know how to add a new node by changing the count to 7.

Besides, is there any way I change the instance type of one of above node? the use case is sometimes one of the nodes is out of memory  so I want to increase the instance type of this node (maybe temporary)

Comment: Why not use autoscaling group with desired count of 6?

Comment: Hi, Marcin: it is actually not aws ec2 but gcp instance. I have changed the post. I know gcp also has auto-scaling. my question is how to delete one specific instance, say the 3rd instance of the 6 nodes and then create a new 3rd instance?

Comment: gcp also [has](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/) auto-scaling.  But with autoscaling you can't just change a single instance. You scale out horizontally, by adding/removing instances based on load.

Comment: in my case, the 6 node means 3 set of nodes. each set is a master and its replica(slave) and each set of node store a part of data (partition). if a master fails due to hardware issue, its slave will promote as master so its data will not lose, but I do need to destroy this problematic node and launch a new one.  I do not think auto scaling will work because auto scaling does not store data I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create the AMI using Packer (another Hashicorp tool). Put that AMI into a Launch Configuration. And then put that Launch Configuration into an Auto Scaling Group (all of this done in Terraform of course). That way you can simply update the AMI value in Launch Config when you want to update AMI.

Comment: I cannot. suppose I relaunch a new instance using Auto scaling I still need to run some command to join the new node to the cluster (redis cluster) and reshard it

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for AWS auto scaling groups (ASG): https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/autoscaling_group

set the desired capacity to 6 and define a launch template with t3.micro instance type.

Comment: Also, the best use case for the instance type change is to update the instance type in the launch template, and then kill one instance. The ASG will detect one instance is down and will pop a new one with the updated instance type.

Comment: Hi, Richard: it is actually not aws ec2 but gcp instance. I have changed the post.in my case, the 6 node means 3 set of nodes. each set is a master and its replica(slave) and each set of node store a part of data (partition). if a master fails due to some issue, its slave will promote as master so its data will not lose, but I need to destroy and replace this problematic node with a new one. but I do not think auto scaling will work because I destroy this node on-purposely.

Comment: you should add a gcp tag to your post, then ^^.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I cannot using AutoScaling. suppose I relaunch a new instance using Auto scaling I still need to run additional command to join the new node to the cluster (redis cluster) and reshard it